# How to allow floating notification and lock screen notification programmatic in flutter

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

To implement push notification, Firebase Cloud Messaging is used.The notification is received successfully in the device but it has to be a pop-up(Floating notification) and it should also be displayed in lock screen.
Notification is composed using Admin SDK in node.js environment. 
Please help to show the notification as a floating and lock-screen notification.

plugin used in flutter is firebase_messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it is not possible.
On some launchers that are enabled when in some it is disabled (for energy-saving purposes I guess) by default.

The user should enable it manually from app settings=>notification section manually.